# How do I check out a subversion repository from a network share?

Tags: svn, networking, repository

I have a Subversion repository on my laptop in my room (windows Vista), but I want to check it out to a computer upstairs (Ubuntu Linux). I put the repository on a network share but I'm not sure how I can check it out to ubuntu.

Note that I don't have subversion server set up on my laptop, I'm just trying todo a checkout from a network directory as if it were local to this computer. What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Do not access a repository directly on a network share](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share)! Even though you might get it to work, you eventually will end up with a completely corrupted repository.

Just set up a server (svnserve or apache) and access it that way. It's easy to set such a server up. And those five minutes you spend setting it up will keep your data safe.

Comment: how would one share a repo by setting one up? Have you got links, I couldn't find any examples :( .

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Please read [Stefan's warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737023/how-do-i-check-out-a-subversion-repository-from-a-network-share/1737294#1737294) before using `file:///` against a network share.**

It may not apply in your specific situation but it is a good general principle.

---

You can't do a checkout against a smb:// share as such; but you can mount the windows share with smbmount i.e.

```
mkdir /mnt/svnserver
sudo smbmount //VISTALAPTOP/subversion /mnt/svnserver -o lfs;
```

after that you can use it as if it were a normal `file:///` repo, located under /mnt/svnserver

Comment: does this just make a copy of the repo? Will I be able to check the code back in?

Comment: No this doesn't do anything to the repo, it just makes your Windows share appear like a folder in Ubuntu.  so you can work on it just as if it were a local repository, you can check in + out as normal.

Comment: Make sure to limit your access to read-only, see also Stefan's post.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch your computers' roles (the Subversion repository on your Ubuntu box), the installation is done in 10 minutes (see the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion))

The installation is so easy it's a no-brainer. Really